# QueryDSL simple query will not cast to object

Tags: java, querydsl

I am testing QueryDSL against the World database in MySql.  I can retrieve the data as a List, but I cannot get it to return as a List.  I am querying via SQL, nothing else. This is what I have.

```
private void getSomething(Connection connection) {
  QCountry country = QCountry.country;
  SQLTemplates dialect = new HSQLDBTemplates(); 
  SQLQuery query = new SQLQueryImpl(connection, dialect);

  //List<Object[]> countries = query.from(country).list(country.all());
  List<QCountry> countries = query.from(country).list(country);

  System.out.println(countries);
  try {
    connection.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I get this error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelationalPath based projection can only be used with generated Bean types`

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate bean types as described here http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html under **Bean class generation**.